# image to text converter not encoding

Tags: python, algorithm, ocr

I tried to convert img to text using textract module. But if the image in cursive means it's not working.

It print like

`VM m K. KM. KKOMKK. .\nWm MK aKKe K. 0% OK... {Kw 3.1% flMK hum/a. KW. KWK am) m1 02.0413, MK, (ma mM/enwnl a...)\nWAWMJMI OWKM. 0.1M ma {Kw mun; KM .Km am not KooK, wwwa. KKK-K .2 WK 0K... .9... KWKW.r am.\nm [Im Km .KmoKK 0.0mm KW. Km, KM .Kw Wu m. Wm. Kw KMK K... .KwK Wt c.K WK KWK a...)\nm); Kw. Fm. m. Kg): .2: 30, K... ma, [Kama/Lug, Ks... . am...  ..., am). a. 3m; ahum Km f1......a...KK. UK\nMK 30.. can, so Km 3... KKK. mKl. m a...) .anK 711an -. 3.21 K... {K ., a... an aw`

Here is my code:

```
import textract
textract.process('test.jpg')
```

[image: Sample image of handwritten text]

Comment: Sorry the link you mentioned is not working

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html)